# Validation Rule for Access form TEXT BOX

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate validation rule as below but it is not working

```vb
If Me.ASSIGNED_REASON.Value = "TEMPORARY USE" Then

Me.TEMP_RETURN_DATE.ValidationRule = Not Null
Me.TEMP_RETURN_DATE.ValidationText = " You must enter return date in box"

End If
```

My requirement is if  ASSIGNED_REASON  is TEMPORARY USE then TEMP_RETURN_DATE should not be empty and if they are trying to save the form without temp return date it should thorough warning message.

please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with *IsNull*:

```vb
If Me!ASSIGNED_REASON.Value = "TEMPORARY USE" Then
    If IsNull(Me!TEMP_RETURN_DATE.Value) Then
        MsgBox "You must enter return date in box"
    End If
End If
```